# IE6 changes DOCTYPE to a bad one

Tags: doctype, internet-explorer-6

I am working with website that has defined following `DOCTYPE`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

When I access that website in `IE6`, `DOCTYPE` is magically changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
```

And.. Ok - it can stay because everything looks fine.. But here is the point - just one page has `DOCTYPE` changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

which I can't stand.

What is the reason of changing `XHTML` to `HTML 4.01` and `HTML 4.0` ?

How can I force `DOCTYPE` in `IE6` to `XHTML` or just `HTML 4.01` ?

Comment: Maybe it has a bit to do with the fact that *IE6 doesn't do XHTML*.  IE doesn't decently support XHTML at all yet.  It's coping as well as it can, considering you're feeding it tag soup.

Comment: If I change `DOCTYPE` in all website to `HTML 4.0.1`, which IE6 supports (isn't it ?), in that one page it changes `DOCTYPE` however to `HTML 4.0`.

Comment: 4.0.1 or 4.01?  Totally different things, and no, IE knows nothing about 4.0.1.  Neither does any other browser for that matter.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `4.01` - question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was unexpected:

HTML comment
    
placed before `<html>` tag causes auto change of the page's doctype.

Answer (score 0):

A browser only displays pages, and never modifies the original page.

The only way your question makes sense is if you're doing "save page as" and wondering why the page that IE saved isn't the same as the page it downloaded. In this case I'd expect the browser converts the page into a some sort of internal representation to make it easier to process, and "save page as" converts that internal representation back into HTML; so that it can save a single file (e.g. with embedded CSS rather than a separate CSS file), ensure that the saved file has correct markup (rather than the original potentially un-corrected markup), etc.

If this isn't what you want, go to "view -> page source" and copy & paste that instead.

Comment: I've done it before and that is the way I noticed that my CSS is good in `HTML 4.01`. However I do not know why it changes `DOCTYPE` in that single page to `HTML 4.0`.

Comment: Ok - that makes things more confusing. For checking your CSS, use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ . For checking your page's markup, etc use http://validator.w3.org/ . For doing silly things and then complaining that they're silly, use http://stackoverflow.com/ .... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only important thing that the doctype does is to force the browser into standards compliance mode. If you don't have a doctype, older browsers will go into Quirks mode; with the doctype (no matter which one you use), the browser will go into Standards mode.

Therefore it really doesn't matter which one you use.

The XHTML doctypes will try to enforce XHTML compliance, but obviously only in browsers that properly support XHTML - IE6 may be problematic here. And of course, specifying XHTML means there's no room for *any* errors at all, or your page won't be rendered.

Other than that, there's really not much to choose between the various doctypes, so my suggestion is to go with the most up-to-date one possible.... which is the HTML5 doctype.

The HTML5 doctype looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's all. Short, simple and to the point. And it does the job for all current browsers (including IE6).

This doesn't mean you have to use any HTML5 features (they obviously won't work IE6 anyway), but it's fully backward compatible, and shouldn't give you any of the weird browser-specific glitches you get with other doctypes.

Hope that helps.