# Internet Explorer automatically changes my DOCTYPE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, doctype, quirks-mode

My web application is triggering quirks mode in IE8. It changes my doctype (html5) and then capitalizes every tag.

When I save the page in Google Chrome and open the saved page in IE8 it works fine.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and how I can fix it?

**What I already tried:**

- I read this and tried playing with comments before `<html>`, without
  luck:
  [IE6 changes DOCTYPE to a bad one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658226/ie6-changes-doctype-to-a-bad-one)
- I saw Google Chrome's saved version had a META tag defining the
  content-type added. Tried inserting this in the page, and tried doing
  this with php's `header()`, but without luck.
- I tried other doctypes I found on this page:
  http://dorward.me.uk/www/ie8/

Using the saved version is not an option because the page is generated with PHP.

**Edit:**
I tried putting the Google Chrome version on the web server, but IE fails on that version too. Are there any server settings which can affect IE's rendering of the page?

**Edit2:**
I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

They were both changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
```

Comment: Can we see the page or the markup?

Comment: The page is 700 lines of code and running in an internal network, so I don't think I can show it easily.

Comment: OK, maybe just post the doctype declaration as copied from the file itself in notepad not via browser insepction. Could be a simple error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Internet Explorer's compatibility mode was on for websites on the internal network.

I could slap myself.